# Google Maps Directions Only

Tags: google-maps, excel, excel-2010, vba

I am working on a project where I want to display a google map in a WebBrowser object in on an excel sheet.  I have accomplished this using this URL....

http://maps.google.com/?saddr=29.9390146,-90.0696139&daddr=29.962506,-90.1930133&f=d&output=embed

I would like to also display the driving directions only for this same link (or a different one).

I cannot find any info on how to get google maps to return the directions only via URL.

AHIA,
LarryR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to check out the GoogleMaps Api:

[Static Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)

[Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)

These API provides you with XML response where you can parse them to get the results displayed.
I made one to find time and distance which you can use as an example:
This is one of my earlier attempts so no XML is used but it will give you an idea how to work with responses from google.

```
Public Function GMap(origin_address As String, destination_address As String, Optional mode As Integer = 1, Optional datatype As Integer = 1)

Dim surl As String
Dim oXH As Object
Dim bodytxt As String
Dim time_e As String
Dim distanc_e As String
Dim strmode As String

If mode = 1 Then
    strmode = "walking"
ElseIf mode = 2 Then
    strmode = "driving"
ElseIf mode = 3 Then
    strmode = "bicycling"
Else
    GMap = "Invalid Mode"
    Exit Function
End If

surl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=;" & _
Replace(origin_address, " ", "+") & "&destinations=" & Replace(destination_address, " ", "+") & _
"&mode=" & strmode & "&sensor=false&units=metric"

Set oXH = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")

With oXH
    .Open "get", surl, False
    .send
    bodytxt = .responseText
End With

bodytxt = Right(bodytxt, Len(bodytxt) - InStr(1, bodytxt, "<text>") - 5)
tim_e = Left(bodytxt, InStr(1, bodytxt, "</text>") - 1)
bodytxt = Right(bodytxt, Len(bodytxt) - InStr(1, bodytxt, "<text>") - 5)
distanc_e = Left(bodytxt, InStr(1, bodytxt, "</text>") - 1)

If datatype = 1 Then
    GMap = CDbl(Replace(tim_e, "mins", ""))
ElseIf datatype = 2 Then
    GMap = CDbl(Replace(distanc_e, "km", ""))
Else
    GMap = "Invalid Data"
End If

Set oXH = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an Excel addin which does what you want: http://www.calvert.ch/geodesix/